# How can one achieve the effect of overriding a base member with more specific type?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to figure out a way for a derived class to be made up of members that have more specific types than those specified in the abstract base class.  Here is some code that works which does what I want, but does not follow the stipulations I mention.  As a result, the client code (in Main) must use a cast on the "BarProperty" which is what I'm trying to avoid, I guess.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConcreteFoo myFoo = new ConcreteFoo();
            myFoo.BarProperty = new ConcreteBar();

            ((ConcreteBar)myFoo.BarProperty).ConcreteBarPrint();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    abstract class AbstractFoo
    {
        protected void FooMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Foo method!");
        }

        public abstract AbstractBar BarProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class ConcreteFoo : AbstractFoo
    {
        private ConcreteBar _concreteBar;

        public override AbstractBar BarProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _concreteBar;
            }
            set
            {
                _concreteBar = (ConcreteBar)value;
            }
        }
    }

    abstract class AbstractBar
    {
        protected void BarMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Bar method!");
        }

    }

    class ConcreteBar : AbstractBar
    {
        public List<int> concreteBarIntList;

        public ConcreteBar()
        {
            concreteBarIntList = new List<int>();
            concreteBarIntList.Add(1);
            concreteBarIntList.Add(2);
            concreteBarIntList.Add(3);
        }

        public void ConcreteBarPrint()
        {
            foreach (int item in concreteBarIntList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What I'd like instead would be to do something like the code below, which of course doesn't compile because ConcreteFoo is trying to override BarProperty using a more specific type than AbstractFoo declared.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConcreteFoo myFoo = new ConcreteFoo();
            myFoo.BarProperty = new ConcreteBar();

            myFoo.BarProperty.ConcreteBarPrint();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    abstract class AbstractFoo
    {
        protected void FooMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Foo method!");
        }

        public abstract AbstractBar BarProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class ConcreteFoo : AbstractFoo
    {
        private ConcreteBar _concreteBar;

        public override ConcreteBar BarProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _concreteBar;
            }
            set
            {
                _concreteBar = (ConcreteBar)value;
            }
        }
    }

    abstract class AbstractBar
    {
        protected void BarMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Bar method!");
        }

    }

    class ConcreteBar : AbstractBar
    {
        public List<int> concreteBarIntList;

        public ConcreteBar()
        {
            concreteBarIntList = new List<int>();
            concreteBarIntList.Add(1);
            concreteBarIntList.Add(2);
            concreteBarIntList.Add(3);
        }

        public void ConcreteBarPrint()
        {
            foreach (int item in concreteBarIntList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You may be thinking "rethink your design" but it's tricky because I'm trying to incorporate some third party code (without changing that code) which doesn't contain some much needed abstract/interface classes to give interchangeable facades to two very similar halves of the code base.  As a result, I've basically had to write my entire program twice, with only minor changes in what types are being used.  I need some way to handle either of two very similar types which unfortunately don't have an interface to demonstrate their similarity to the compiler.

Comment: Are you worried about the `get` or the `set`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the basic scenario, try giving `BarProperty` a [generic type with a constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo<TBar> where TBar : AbstractBar
{
    public abstract TBar BarProperty { get; }
}

public class ConcreteFoo : AbstractFoo<ConcreteBar>
{
    public override ConcreteBar BarProperty { get { ...; } }
}
```

Based on additional comments, it sounds like the real challenge in this particular case is multiple classes that don't share a base type or interface, but have similar shapes and behaviors. In this case, one solution is to create a **proxy class**:

```
public class MyProxy
{
    private readonly Foo _foo;
    private readonly Bar _bar;

    public MyProxy(Foo foo)
    {
        this._foo = foo;
    }

    public MyProxy(Bar bar)
    {
        this._bar = bar;
    }

    public string SharedProperty1
    {
        get
        {
            if(this._foo != null)
            {
                return this._foo.SharedProperty1;
            }
            if(this._bar != null)
            {
                return this._bar.SharedProperty1;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Both underlying objects are null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I had been trying to figure out some way to get generics involved but hadn't been able to think of the right way.  I will see if I can adapt this approach into what I'm working on.  It might take me all day ;) but I'll come back with more comments and/or choose this answer after I can try it out.

Comment: what if you want to reference a bunch of abstractFoo in a list with possibly multiple types coming back from different implementations? could I use something more generic then AbstractFoo<TBar>? like AbstractFoo?

Comment: @Eluvatar you could create an implementation like `MultiFoo : AbstractFoo<AbstractBar>`

Comment: I'm kinda stumbling around with this, trying to see if there's some way to adapt it to what I want to do.  In doing so, I'm led to ask this additional question about your example.  Is there a way to do something like the code/pseudocode below?  
  
class Foo<T> where T (is a ConcreteBar1 or a ConcreteBar2) {}  
  
Keep in mind, ConcreteBar1 and ConcreteBar2 have very similar structures, but they don't inherit from an interface that documents the similarities I'm trying to use.

Comment: @bubbleking if CB1 and CB2 are in different type hierarchies, there's nothing to be done. We've now drifted into "wait, what exactly are you trying to do here?" If you could describe the actual problem, we may be able to help you find a better approach.

Comment: Hmmm. I think this might just be a problem that can't be fixed without editing the third party code I didn't want to alter.  Specifically I am using Amazon's MWS Products API which has a C# library [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/cSharp.html/176-6313567-6521147) if you're curious. Almost all queries have two versions, one for each type of supported product ID (SKU, ASIN). They derive them from abstract classes, but these don't contain definitions for all the common aspects. As a result... (continued)

Comment: ... even though most of the types seem interchangeable between ASIN and SKU versions, the interfaces and abstract classes aren't complete enough to let the compiler know this.  For example, even though the types "GetCompetitivePricingForSkuResponse" and "GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse" both contain a List<> of result objects that have virtually the same structure, client code sees them as totally different because these List<> objects are defined in the concrete derived classes, in parallel, instead of in the interface or abstract class...

Comment: As such, in my code, I can't find a way to seemlessly toggle between using these two things:

`GetCompetitivePricingForSkuResponse.GetCompetitivePricingForSKUResult[0]`
...
`GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse.GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult[0]`

... even though they're essentially the same. What I'd like is for my user to switch between the two parallel sets of behavior using a radio button to choose the ID type they want to search by.  Unfortunately this has caused me to write almost my entire program twice... one for ASIN and once for SKU with no difference except names.

Comment: @bubbleking see my revised answer

Comment: @RexM That's brilliant, thanks!  I believe that will do the trick in this scenario.